# Android Record Audio in screen

Tags: java, android, json, audio, record

I use this [library](https://github.com/ParadiseHell/PianoView) for the piano, but I need to record the sounds from the piano into an audio file, how do I do this? I read about MediaRecorder, but is there only a microphone recording, or have I not found something?